# Jquery Cycle through table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows, cycle

I need to set up jQuery to cycle through table rows. The table should always show only one row. When I click the link, the previous row or the next row should be shown.

The basic HTML structure is:

```
<div>
<a href="">Next</a>
<table>
  <tr><td>text1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text4</td></tr>
</table>
<a href="">Previous</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? What trouble have you run into?

Comment: And what do you mean by "cycling through rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give ids to your elements:

```
<a id="next" href="">Next</a>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>text1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text4</td></tr>
</table>
<a id="prev" href="">Previous</a>
```

Then, hide all elements except for the first one:

```
$("#myTable tr").hide().eq(0).show();
```

Finally, make the "Next" and "Previous" buttons toggle the visibility of the adjacent siblings, if exist:

```
$("#next").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myTable tr:visible").next().show().prev().hide(); // Will do nothing if the visible element is the last one
});

$("#prev").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myTable tr:visible").prev().show().next().hide(); // Will do nothing if the visible element is the first one
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean by "cycling through rows," but some building blocks:

1. You can use CSS selectors (just about all of CSS3 [plus some](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) to find elements in the DOM. For instance, this finds all `a` elements:

   ```
   var links = $('a');
   ```
2. You can hook events on those via [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (or if you're using an older copy of jQuery, [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind)).
3. When handling an event, you can use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the default action of the event (for instance, preventing a click on a link from following the link) and/or [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) (to prevent the event bubbling up the DOM), or do both by returning `false` out of your event handler.
4. jQuery is set-based, so a jQuery instance can be a wrapper around multiple elements, e.g. `var rows = $('tr');`.
5. You can index into a jQuery instance to access the raw DOM element at that point in the matched set, e.g. `rows[2]` is the third row in the set.

So as an example, if you added the class `"next"` to your "next" link:

```
<a href="" class="next">Next</a>
```

...you could find it with a selector and hook the `click` event:

```
$('a.next').on('click', function(event) {
    // This function is called when the link is clicked
    // ...

    // Prevent the browser from actually following the link
    // and stop the event bubbling
    return false;
});
```

So you might keep an index for which row is "current", index into a jQuery instance that's wrapping those rows, and do something with it on click.

Well worth spending an hour or two reading through the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com). Literally takes that long, and you get a huge reward.